# reproducing an Excel IF statement in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I have a table that has the following column headers:

```
customer_id, Stage1,     Stage2,     Stage3
xxxxxx,      21-01-2019, 22-01-2019, 23-01-2019
yyyyyy,      22-02-2019,           , 24-02-2019
```

I want to create a forth column, `Stage2_New`, that if the relevant cell in `Stage2` is blank, assigns the date in `Stage1`, in excel it will be: `IF(C3=" ", B3, C3)`

What is the SQL code I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that by blank you mean `NULL`. If so, you can use `COALESCE` :

```
COALESCE(Stage2, Stage1)
```

When its first argument is `NULL`, `COALESCE` returns the value given as second argument. Else, it returns the first argument unchanged.`Stage

To actually add the new column and set its content:

```
-- add the new column
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN Stage2_New DATE; -- or the correspondig datatype

-- update the values
UPDATE mytable SET Stage2_New = COALESCE(Stage2, Stage1);
```

If you need are dealing with empty strings as well as `NULL` values:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Stage2, ''), Stage1)
```